# Angular routing based on promise - 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, es6-promise

I want to either show/hide a route based on an API call (Promise returned). If I add a conditional based on the promise value as below, the route is correctly shown/hidden correctly when I visit the URL through navigation.

However, when I hit refresh on the URL, I get a 404 error. I am completely new to Angular, JS and promises so I can't understand what exactly is going on here, or how this is resolved.

```
let toggle: boolean = await fetch("/pageToggle")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => parseInt(response) === 1)
        .catch(() => false);
```

```
    if (toggle) {
             $stateProvider.state('maintenance.correspondence', {
                url: '/correspondence',
                data: {
                    title: 'Correspondence',
                    header: {
                        heading: 'Correspondence',
                        subheading: 'Correspondence'
                    }
                },

                template: '<correspondence></correspondence>',
                controller: ($scope: IScope) => {
                },
                onExit: (BreadCrumbs: BreadCrumbs) => {
                    BreadCrumbs.reset();
                },
                onEnter: (BreadCrumbs: BreadCrumbs, $stateParams: IStateParamsService) => {
                    BreadCrumbs.add("Correspondence", "Correspondence", null, "maintenance.correspondence");
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Another point to clarify is that I only inherited this code from another developer, and all I am trying to do is fix the issue with the redirection.

The URLs look like using HTML5 mode. The URL's are like
`https://localhost:3000/#/maintenance/correspondence/`

Edit **4/11/2021**:

I've made some progress with this. What I've observed is that the 404 only happens when I do a conditional (based on promise result) around the state. Regardless of the result of the promise boolean, Angular is not able to resolve the route.

If I remove the conditional, I don't get the 404, but I do need a way to conditionally not show the route based as needed.

I have been looking at the resolve{} method to see if I can do the API call there, but I am not sure how or where to add the conditional for the state based on the promise. So I think this is now essentially working around AngularJS state providers to do what I need, if I understand this right.

Can someone please help me implement this?

***Edit - 5/11/2021***
I've been trying a few things, but still stuck with this. Can someone please help?

Comment: `.then(value => { return value  })` doesn't do anything (it receives a value and just returns this same value). Besides, you are mixing the `await` syntax and the `.then()` syntax. Remove the `.then()` completely. You are also missing the response transformation : `const response = await fetch(...); const data = await response.json()`. I don't think `fetch` can fetch a boolean directly. JSON yes, text yes, blob yes, but boolean? I don't think so.

Comment: @jeremy Thille I have updated the code based on your comment. However the 404 problem when I refresh the page still persists. Could you please point me in the right direction so I can resolve that?

Comment: I don't really know. I stopped using Angular 1 when Angular 2 came out back in 2016 :/ I was just pointing out general Javascript syntax mistakes

Comment: @Jeremy Thille I think Angular 1/2+ doesn't matter in this case? I feel I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Exactly, that's why my first comment is about general JS stuff (async/await) and not Angular. But you said you are now using `const response = await fetch(...); const data = await response.json();` instead of `.then()`, and still getting an Angular routing problem, so I guess the issue is now in Angular. And I forgot everything about Angular 1 five years ago

Comment: ok, thank you. Yes, I am getting boolean true/false values from the server now into the 'toggle' variable. It's just that it displays correctly when navigating to the URL, but shows 404 when browser refresh is tried. Please check my edited code above.

Comment: Aaaaah, of course it does. That's a totally different problem. We solved problem 1, now that's problem 2, the next problem in line. When you refresh your page, the browser makes a GET request to your server, at the URL `/correspondence`. And your server has no such route. This is a server-side problem now. Handle all unknown routes by sending back your `index.html`, which contains your Angular app. Then, Angular will start up and take care of the routing

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to move this to chat since it's getting long but it seems like I don't have permissions to do so. So, how is this related to Promise? Because the 404 happens only for the URL I have under promise; all the other URLS, I am able to refresh. Also, my app doesn't have an index.html :( It has an index.scala.html, but that doesn't seem like what I want. I am new to UI programming, could you please guide me as to how to find it?

Comment: Not really, sorry. I take some time to write a few comments but I'm working so I can't go full chat. Besides, as I mentioned, I forgot everything about Angular 1 a long time ago, and I know nothing about Scala...

Comment: No problem! Would you know how/if promise would have anything to do with the 404? If there's someone else could help, I'd really appreciate it.